# How to convert scientific notation string to a big.Int?

Tags: go

In golang I have a large number in a string like this: "4.49955000449955e+24".

How can I convert this to a `big.Int`?

Comment: If i understood it well: `var converted, err = strconv.ParseFloat(number,  64); var big = big.NewFloat(converted).Int(nil)`

Answer (score 8):

use [big.ParseFloat](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#ParseFloat) to get a `big.Float` and then the [Int](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Float.Int) method to convert it to a `big.Int`:

```
flt, _, err := big.ParseFloat(input, 10, 0, big.ToNearestEven)
if err != nil {
    /* handle a parsing error here */
}
var i = new(big.Int)
i, acc := flt.Int(i)
```

[see it on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Jkzx2Z36HLS).

By adjusting the `prec` argument to `ParseFloat` you can control the precision of the intermediate float — it takes at least 72 bits of precision for your example input to come out exactly (to a value ending in ten zeroes) but the default if you pass 0 is 64 bits.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.